# How to make setInterval in javascript last for more than 50 days?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

I know the maximum of setInterval time is less than max 32-bit unsigned integer but that not enough for my case, I need setInterval to have time more than 50 days how I can accomplish such task ? 
Regards,

Comment: Probably have a counter running and set a new intervall at 49 days?

Comment: Do you think the page will be opened for more than 50 days?

Comment: It seems like an XY problem. Why don't you explain why you need this?

Comment: It is better to check `current date` and than, in this day, set interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering what you actually asked: You can't. Instead, you'd have it recur more often than that and have conditional logic so you only did something every 50th (or whatever) day.

Example: Once every 75 days:

```
var nextEvent = new Date();
nextEvent.setDate(nextEvent.getDate() + 75); // JS dates handle month rollover for you
setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date() < nextEvent) {
        return;
    }

    // ...do your processing...

    // Set up for next time
    nextEvent = new Date();
    nextEvent.setDate(nextEvent.getDate() + 75);

}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // Once a day
```

**But**, I'm not guaranteeing the browser will actually keep firing that interval timer for days on end.

Comment: Then wouldn't be a better approach to store the ticker date somewhere (localStorage or cookie), refresh the page periodically to be sure that a smaller interval keeps firing, and only when the `date >= tickerDate-fewMinutes && date <= tickerDate` set a new, more precise `setTimeout( tick, tickerDate - now )`?

Comment: @Kaiido: Storing in local storage is a good idea, yes; endless page refresh, no, in my view. :-) But really, we'd need to know more about the actual underlying requirement; odds are that the whole approach needs a rethink.

Comment: Last points are totally agreed. For the periodic refresh... I wouldn't do that either but between that and hoping that a 50 days old page still runs well ... don't know, and if one day I have to think about it for one of my projects, I'll go one step back and rethink the why I need it better.